# Why does importing javafx.scene.control.Button fail with Toolkit Not Initialized?

Tags: swing, clojure, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm trying basic stuff with JavaFX with Clojure, on Java8 64-bit (1.8.0_05-b13) on Windows 7.

In my imports (whether in .clj file or in REPL), I can `(import 'javafx.scene.control.ButtonBuilder)` (and other builders), but I cannot `(import 'javafx.scene.control.Button)` or any other final widget from javax.scene.control.

If I try importing `javafx.scene.control.Button` or other widget, I get the `Toolkit Not Initialized` error.  Same with trying to create the button via the ButtonBuilder, even though the ButtonBuilder class itself seems to work fine, and it appears I'm quite able to import other things from the javafx heirarchy.

In order to get it to work I have to force the toolkit to initialize, as shown here, which I think leaves me with an Orphan panel somewhere, which feels kind of dirty: https://gist.github.com/zilti/6286307

```
(ns hello.core
  (:import (javafx.event ActionEvent EventHandler)
           (javafx.scene Scene SceneBuilder)
           (javafx.scene.layout VBox VBoxBuilder)
           ;;(javafx.scene.control Button) -- MUST COMMENT THIS OUT OR FAIL
           (javafx.scene.control ButtonBuilder)
           (javafx.stage Stage StageBuilder)))

(defonce force-toolkit-init (javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.))
```

This was not the case with Java 7 and javafxrt.jar.  The only discussion about this I've found (on SO) shows this is required for Swing interop, which I'm not using.

Can someone please explain why this is required now with Java8, and why it only seems to be required for final widgets like Button?

This looks like a magic workaround.  Is there a real solution somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX requires initialization code which starts UI threads, handles application running modes and load native libraries.

JavaFX application are strongly advised to start from a class extending `javafx.appication.Application` which will perform all initialization routines.

Calling `JFXPanel` will perform initialization too but it's kinda hack (unless you are really using swing and FX in one app).

Comment: So the fact that other things seem to work, sort of, like the main window opening up, is basically an undefined, yet still useful behavior?  I've previously used the :gen-class method to derive from Application, but I wanted to see if I could have REPL control of the GUI.  So far I can create widgets (after initializing), but when I close the window I'm unable to start it up again.  This is actually the main goal, to reduce the startup time to negligible time.

Comment: yep, and your original approach was more correct. About inability to start windows again better ask in another question with more details.